# Testing model relationships without coupling with implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm trying to refactor a testing suite that's way too tightly coupled to the implementation, but I'm having problems with relationships. For example, I have a simple user model:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_role
  delegate :executive?, to: :user_role
end
```

And this is the UserRole model:

```
class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  def executive?
    name == 'Executive'
  end
end
```

Testing the UserRole model is easy, but, following thorough testing rules, I think I should also test the AdminUser model, because I expect it to respond to .executive?, and that's where my problem starts.

If I follow the usual unit testing rules, I should be testing only AdminUser, so I could mock UserRole.executive? and get it done, but... What if UserRole's implementation changes over time? What if I want to change UserRole to another model or a more complex object to follow more complex rules? I would need to change AdminUser's tests to follow the new implementation, and that feels kinda dirty, because being anal about unit testing, I should only be testing the 'what', not the 'how'.

Am I being way too strict here? Is there a better way to do this that I'm not grasping?

Answer (score 1):

What if you didn't know anything about the implementation of AdminUser? How would you know if it responds to `#executive?`? Simple:

```
expect(admin_user.respond_to?(:executive?)).to be_true
```

Write another test for `#executive?` in `UserRole`, and you're done.

If you move `#executive?` out of `UserRole`, or change its behavior, you'll need to update the test, of course. But the behavior of AdminUser doesn't change....or rather, its behavior with respect to that one method is entirely determined by another class. Testing the method in more than one place doesn't help.